# Detection of certain stochastic process

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, bayesian, sampling-theory

Hello math stack exchange!
Suppose we have arbitrary function of stochastic processes $X_i(t)$, like $$Y(t) = X_1(t) + X_2(t) - X_3(t) + X_4(t)  ....,$$  more generally $Y(t) = f(X_1(t), X_2(t), X_3(t)...).$

Is there a general theory of detecting the "**presence**" of certain process $X_a(t)$ by observing only $Y(t)$? 
Each process $X_i(t)$ are not noise but behave similarly with different parameters, doesn't change much in short term, possibly stationary. $X_a(t)$ changes very abruptly and I want to detect the presence of $X_a(t)$ in $Y(t)$.

This might be somewhat related to bayesian inference stuffs but I'm not fully sure where to start looking at. Even random throwing of keywords would be helpful thanks!

Comment: Change point detection in stochastic processes has a ton of literature.  Do you know in particular that you will be selecting over just a few possible stochastic processes?  In that case, you may make more assumptions...

Comment: @Adam I was actually thinking queueing system where Xi(t) of constant rate Poisson arrival processes and Xa(t) of some process that has abruptly increasing rate parameter w.r.t time. So it's basically detecting if process with abruptly changing rate parameter is in the queueing system,  or it's just that multiple additional peaceful process has entered the system. Thank you

Comment: Maybe see the following?:

https://arxiv.org/abs/1206.6627